# Java deepToString to array - matrix multiplication

Tags: java, arrays

Can someone help me with something?
I'm trying to convert a string which was initially created using the `deepToString()` method, back to an array. I've tried pretty much anything I could find on Stack Overflow… but no luck.

This is what I have right now:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test3 {
    static int matrix [][] = new int[2][2];

    public static int[][] matrixGenerator() {
        Random r = new Random( );
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
                matrix[i][j] = r.nextInt( 10000 );
            }
        }
        return matrix;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String matrix1 = Arrays.deepToString(matrixGenerator());
        String matrix2 = Arrays.deepToString(matrixGenerator());
        System.out.println(matrix1 + '\n' + matrix2);
    }
}
```

This outputs

> [[6030, 3761], [6605, 5582]]

and

> [[1799, 461], [1197, 1012]]

Which is exactly what I need. Now I'm trying to do a matrix multiplication using this piece of code.

```
int m1rows = matrix1.length;
int m1cols = matrix1[0].length;
int m2cols = matrix2[0].length;

int[][] result = new int[m1rows][m2cols];
    for (int i = 0; i < m1rows; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < m2cols; j++) {
          for (int k = 0; k < m1cols; k++) {
             result[i][j] += matrix1[i][k] * matrix2[k][j];
       }
    }
 }
```

The problem is that I cannot loop through the array because it's not actually an array, it's a string. Which makes sense. Can someone tell me how can I loop, though? I've tried to convert the string back to array - but no luck

Comment: If it is a string, can't you build an array by splitting on [] and , ?

Comment: split it and then parse it to integer t do your manipulations :)

Comment: Can I ask how, please? It's just that my brain is on "lock down" right now :(

Comment: Your `matrixGenerator()` returns an `int[][]`. Why don't you use those arrays instead of converting them to `String` ?

Comment: why do you want to convert Array to String and then back to array? any specific needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need convertion of matrix to String and then back to matrix?
Can you simply use

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int matrix1 [][] = matrixGenerator();
        int matrix2 [][] = matrixGenerator();
        int matrix3 [][] = matrixMultiplication(matrix1, matrix2);
        String matrix1Str = Arrays.deepToString(matrix1);
        String matrix2Str = Arrays.deepToString(matrix2);
        String matrix3Str = Arrays.deepToString(matrix3);
        System.out.println(matrix1Str+'\n'+matrix2Str+'\n'+matrix3Str);
    }

    public static int[][] matrixGenerator(){
        int matrix [][] = new int[2][2];
        Random r = new Random( );
        for(int i=0; i < matrix.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j < matrix[i].length; j++){
                matrix[i][j] = r.nextInt( 10000 );
            }
        }
        return matrix;
    }

    public static int[][] matrixMultiplication(int[][] matrix1, int[][] matrix2) {
        int m1rows = matrix1.length;
        int m1cols = matrix1[0].length;
        int m2cols = matrix2[0].length;

        int[][] result = new int[m1rows][m2cols];
            for (int i=0; i< m1rows; i++){
               for (int j=0; j< m2cols; j++){
                  for (int k=0; k< m1cols; k++){
                     result[i][j] += matrix1[i][k] * matrix2[k][j];
               }
            }
         }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: you are a star! that was exactly what I needed! thank you!